# After samadhi what?

Tags: consciousness, samadhi

> Last year I experienced samadhi, full state of awareness. Mind's
>   thoughts stopped for days and I can't describe with feelings and words
>   the complete experience.

It was like the wheels of my mind stopped. I was living the present moment very loud. It was like I was standing on top of my head and my conscioussness was dramatically expanding.

I wasn't practicing anything and I had no idea what it was until someone who was in the same state since his birth explained to me.

> Before come to this, a few days ago I had some scary lucid dreams
>   with dream paralisis.
>
> Then 11:11 synchronicities on my clock

I've seen light in the dark. And it was not coming through my eyes.

The experience of samadhi lasted a few days and it had a curve and a peak. I felt like the third eye was openned. And I still can't believe that I'm talking about all these things.

> In it's peak I felt like I was living in the moment for first time in
>   my life.

There was no past or future, it was just now.

And everything was so calmful and alive... and there was nothing to worry about.

And I knew that I could be whoever I wanted to be no matter what. Like I was in deep sleep since I was a kid and I finally woke up.
I knew that I could change and improve and manipulate my body and my mind like a toy.

No skills, no title, nothing was impossible, it was just a matter of choice.

I felt like everything including me were connected.

It is difficult to describe exactly how I felt... but  It was like i could feel the vibrations of everything around me from a distance. I could hear high frequencies when someone was focusing in me. I could see green auras orbiting in the air.

I was looking the world outside and everybody was like zombies of their own minds. And I realized that I used to be like them too.

Everything was so clear and easy to understand without thinking at all, like in Limitless movie.

It was like I was sleeping in my entire life and I finally woke up in the real world.

Everything was so real... I had no good or bad feelings, no thoughts, just consciousness in an epic level I didn't know that ever existed.

I was looking the trees, the birds and the fountain like I had never seen anything like this before. And they were stunning.

No word was coming in my mind, no thought, nothing. But I could easily participate in a high quality conversation without using my mind at all. But I didn't want to talk, I just wanted to listen. For first time in my life I wanted to listen... ONLY!

But I had my senses increased at 100000% and I felt my body and my mind like a cheap version of my real self. I felt my body like a human avatar for my soul. I was not sure about god etc... till then. I realized that everything is much more than we understand.

My body and my mind was like a toy. On top of my head with a distance of the physical body was my new self that could easily manipulate my physical mind and body just by desire.

> So... what was it, where it came from and why?   and last but not
>   least... what's next?

Comment: by the way I need to mention that I don't take any drugs.

Comment: There are many incidents of "spontaneous awakening" or "sudden awakening". You can find descriptions online, along with video interviews, such as at "Buddha At The Gas Pump". A researcher is doing work on "Persistent Non-Symbolic Experience", Dr. Jeffrey Martin at Harvard I think. Look for info on Nonduality also, there are many web sites about that, and discussion areas available.

Comment: Congratulations! You have been blessed. To investigate 'what's next' you might listen carefully to the teachings of the sages and masters. Rupert Spira, Mooji or Sadhguru on youtube might be a good start. From the Buddhist literature.I'd be tempted to suggest checking out the poetry of Zen master Hongzhi, but you're spoiled for choice..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buddhist meditation is not clinging to (i.e., not getting infatuated about) experienced phenomena.

> Last year I experienced samadhi, full state of awareness. Mind's
>   thoughts stopped for days and I can't describe with feelings and words
>   the complete experience.

This is a type of samadhi. Samadhi is the absence of thoughts, just like an orange is orange in colour. Why are you making a bid deal about something that is totally normal?

Samadhi is the absence of thinking therefore why have you now engaged in a path that is totally the opposite of samadhi, which is thinking about samadhi rather than dwelling in samadhi?

> It was like the wheels of my mind stopped. I was living the present
>   moment very loud. It was like I was standing on top of my head and my
>   conscioussness was dramatically expanding.

The thinking of the mind stopped. Consciousness expanded. This is normal. But now the wheels of the mind have started up again by asking these questions.

> I wasn't practicing anything and I had no idea what it was until
>   someone who was in the same state since his birth explained to me.

I think anyone who believes they have been in samadhi since birth is probably crazy. I would ignore them.

> Before come to this, a few days ago I had some scary lucid dreams
>   with dream paralisis.

Dreams are just mental fabrications. In sleep, spiritually, changes of consciousness can occur due to changes in neurology. Whatever happened is just ordinary. Nothing to be infatuated with.

> I've seen light in the dark. And it was not coming through my eyes.

This does not matter. What matters is to view all experience with equanimity & non-attachment.

> The experience of samadhi lasted a few days and it had a curve and a
>   peak. I felt like the third eye was openned. And I still can't believe
>   that I'm talking about all these things.

The impression here is of reading too many books & imagining too many things. If the mind really had samadhi for 3 days, the mind would be calm.

Did you take drugs?

> In it's peak I felt like I was living in the moment for first time in
>   my life.

Again, reading too many book, maybe by Eckhart Tolle.

> There was no past or future, it was just now.

In reality, there is no real past & no real future. Why are you flabbergasted over what is real?

> And everything was so calmful and alive... and there was nothing to
>   worry about.

Your mind does not sound calm to me.

> And I knew that I could be whoever I wanted to be no matter what.

Yep... as i suspected, reading too many books or listening to too many gurus.

> Like I was in deep sleep since I was a kid and I finally woke up.

If you woke yup, why are you asking these questions on the internet?

> I knew that I could change and improve and manipulate my body and my
>   mind like a toy.

If so, what are you not controlling your mind, now?

> No skills, no title, nothing was impossible, it was just a matter of
>   choice.

Wow... you sound brainwashed by some new age teachings. Again, if you could do the impossible, why are you here asking these questions?

> I felt like everything including me were connected.

You felt like you were Jesus Christ or Sai Baba, it sounds like.

> It is difficult to describe exactly how I felt... but  It was like i
>   could feel the vibrations of everything around me from a distance. I
>   could hear high frequencies when someone was focusing in me. I could
>   see green auras orbiting in the air.

The "I", "I", "I", is getting tedious and unrelated to Buddhism. There is a Hindu forum you can ask your question on, if the mind is unable to give up delusions of "I".

> I was looking the world outside and everybody was like zombies of
>   their own minds. And I realized that I used to be like them too.

But now you are the next Messiah & World Saviour? Now you will write books, make videos, be a guest on Oprah and have thousands of zombies follow you as your disciples?

> Everything was so clear and easy to understand without thinking at
>   all, like in Limitless movie.

If so, why now without understanding?

> It was like I was sleeping in my entire life and I finally woke up in
>   the real world.

You sound confused to me & lacking peace. When my mind 1st experienced peace in meditation, it remained peaceful after that. I was amazed peace actually existed because previously I felt there was no such thing as peace. Meditation was about "peace" to me rather than about "awakening". I think you have been reading too many books or listening to too many gurus. When the mind knows peace, it remains dwelling in that peace & that peace is a functional (rather than dysfunctional) state.

> Everything was so real... I had no good or bad feelings, no thoughts,
>   just consciousness in an epic level I didn't know that ever existed.

The infatuation currently occurring to your mind shows your mind did have good feelings, otherwise you would currently not be drunk on whatever experience you imagine you had.

> I was looking the trees, the birds and the fountain like I had never
>   seen anything like this before. And they were stunning.

If they were stunning, there was good feelings.

> No word was coming in my mind, no thought, nothing. But I could easily
>   participate in a high quality conversation without using my mind at
>   all. But I didn't want to talk, I just wanted to listen. For first
>   time in my life I wanted to listen... ONLY!

So what?

> But I had my senses increased at 100000% and I felt my body and my
>   mind like a cheap version of my real self. I felt my body like a human
>   avatar for my soul. I was not sure about god etc... till then. I
>   realized that everything is much more than we understand.

As I said, reading too many books. Avatar & soul are not related to Buddhism.

> My body and my mind was like a toy. On top of my head with a distance
>   of the physical body was my new self that could easily manipulate my
>   physical mind and body just by desire.

Mentally, you currently appear unstable; sounding like you believe you are the many manifestations of Krishna or Brahma.

[image]

> So... what was it, where it came from and why?   and last but not
>   least... what's next?

Why don't you ask your friend who has been in samadhi since birth? Otherwise, if you wish to practise the Buddhist path, simply let it all go; simply stop clinging to whatever experience the mind had; which means giving up all of the "spiritual materialism/egoism" that is currently occurring. Whatever was experienced is the past and the past is now over. Remember, you claimed there was no past. In Buddhism, if a beneficial mental state cannot be maintained then it is worthless.

In summary:

1. Samadhi (lucid unified consciousness) occurs when the mind stops thinking & lets go, which can occur in  formal meditation, spontaneously or when people take drugs. That is what it is & that is what it came from.
2. In Buddhism, what is next is always the Noble Eightfold Path, which is based in abandoning craving, attachment & manufacturing egoism towards every experience without exception. What is next is Nibbana or Peace.
3. What is **not** next is believing: "**I am** God", "**I am** World Saviour", "**I am** Awakened", etc. In Buddhism, what is next is not "I am". "I am" is a belief found in Judaism, Christianity & Hinduism but not Buddhism. Buddhism teaches "*anatta*", which means "*not self*". The Buddha taught:

> The eye is not yours: let go of it. Your letting go of it will be for
>   your long-term happiness & benefit... The ear... The nose... The
>   tongue... The body... The mind is not yours: let go of it. Your
>   letting go of it will be for your long-term happiness & benefit...
>   Whatever arises in dependence on mind-contact, experienced either as
>   pleasure, as pain, or as neither-pleasure-nor-pain, that too is not
>   yours: let go of it. Your letting go of it will be for your long-term
>   happiness & benefit.
>
> [Na Tumhaka Sutta: Not Yours](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.101.than.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Perhaps this is not a valuable phenomenon to your local tradition. I wasn't doing any meditation. I'm not dogmatic either. This experience was so powerful and unique to me that shaked my whole existence... and make me seek here in a buddhism Q/A website for explanations. Do you have any idea why it happened, where it came from and what's next? Perhaps there are many people out there who are interested too.

Comment: OK. I will see if i can offer more to you. In the mean time, listen to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1oK4Vt_ntY

Comment: I found your answer very educative. I'm a christian, just by local religion. I wasn't meditating and haven't read the books you guessed. I've come across new age articles and videos as I was looking for same experiences but what I describe is my experience. I've really had these impressions. As I mentioned it lasted only a few days and then I went back to "normal" daylife. Everything seemed easy yes, in daylife, because the mind was finally clear, but couldn't explain what was happening.

Comment: In the past I felt that your perspective was helpful, but lately your answers seem to be more harsh and argumentative. This particular question and asker probably will not benefit from that approach, although he has politely accepted your reply.

Comment: I found the video (in your comment) interesting. The conversing voice mentioned in the middle is an experience I have had since childhood. Is this common? People do not mention it.

Comment: It might sound weird, but the way he answered gave me a deep lesson. Looking back the samadhi experience over and over is probably the reason that I'm not living in the moment anymore.

Comment: It is also true that I did feel like I had some super powers since I was lucid even in my dreams. I could decide at anytime in my sleep to wake up. Even my eyes were not getting close deeply anymore. However I could also realise that I was not the only one. The guy who told me that what I was experiencing is called eudaimonia in greek, was in nirvana state since he could remember his self..and I thought he had completed some kind of path in a previous life...

Comment: He only said to me to keep low profile, don't start to believe that I am some kind of world leader ...and have patience with other people because I could have a wider understanding than average.

Comment: I need to mention that I was having a continuous itching on top of my head (crown) under the skin, like there was an energetic flow coming in.. for weeks

Comment: I could feel other people's energetic fields. I started having interest in crystals and new age staff... because I could actually feel crystals from distance. I also discovered that I had very strong radiesthetic abilities. I could write weird sentences that were definetely not coming out of my head by using pendulums or even without any tool... (aka automatic writing)

Comment: The lesson that I get from all of these is to not get stacked to these. They obviously didn't make me brighter and were absolute distractive.

Comment: Well, in that case, i guess Dhammadhatu is much more knowledgeable of what is best, as his approach was correct for you, so my opinion of him is restored, and my humility is corrected. Thank you MrNobody for replying. I am glad that you have gained so much from asking this question. I wish you well.

Answer (score 4):

> So... what was it, where it came from and why?

What you have described sounds very much like the experience of Udayabbaya ñana or the knowledge of Arising and Passing Away. You can search for these terms and figure out more about this. You can also refer to this [description](https://www.dharmaoverground.org/dharma-wiki/-/wiki/Main/Arising+and+Passing+Away) of this stage by Daniel Ingram.

As to where it came from, only you can answer that question. Something you undertook, like self-enquiry might have resulted in this. Generally these things are unclear at that time but with sufficient understanding of oneself and the world, it can become more clear.

Why did it happen? Because it is natural, it might present itself to any one who looks inside. For some it may not happen with years of practice, but for some others it can happen by just looking at things with mere curiosity. There could be various reasons for this, ranging from past karma to genetic differences, but its not worth pondering too much on these as these are outside one's control anyways.

> what's next?

Spectacular as it may be, it is not the final stage or end result of one's insight practice. In fact, some texts like Visuddhimagga refer to it as the beginning of actual insight practice. The long term goal is to use this to reach stream entry, or the first stage of awakening. To get there you might need regular practice and most probably also guidance from an experienced teacher.

In the short term, it is better not to hold on to these experiences, as it is transient and not repeatable. The clarity might not remain same and identifying with past experiences can cause added suffering. As clarity fades, you might find yourself in difficult territories, so learning and practicing letting go will probably help a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunetely I can't upvote your comment due to my reputation. Your answers look very related to my experience. I will accept it  if there won't be anything more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

While I have never had such an experience that lasted for days, I have had some rather zen moments upon reaching epiphanies during contemplative thought. I think the longest was about 15 minutes long and happened when I realized the true nature of the universe.

Again, not during meditation but during a period of "focused unfocusing". I would simply relax, get rid of all external stimuli, and play a ringing bell tone. Once there I'd follow any thought down its' rabbit hole and see where it leads me.

No single procedure regarding resting and focusing the mind covers all the ways it may occur. You may have your own self-learned method or stimuli that brings you to a similar or (obviously) greater point. Consider me suitably impressed, but not surprised. We all have our particular strengths - maybe this one is yours?

I'd certainly explore it further. No matter what your faith or beliefs being able to focus your mind in such a manner will have a myriad of benefits.

Learning things about your mind is a significant step forward in humanity. Congratulations!! Enjoy the ride.

Answer (score 1):

Eckart Tolle describes what I understand as a spontaneous awakening in his book “The Power of Now.’ His experience was not within the context of Buddhist meditation practice, and for me it misses the connection and explanations of an individual ‘experience’ to Buddhist teachings. Though American Zen Buddhist often adopt the ‘no scriptures’ rebellion of monks forced to endlessly recite and memorize scriptures, I believe study of Buddhist scriptures is beneficial to American Buddhists in order to build framework of reference for walking the Buddhist path. In short, it might be good to look to Buddhist teachings to put your experience in that framework. Then again, you could work with your experience within any frame of reference, or none or none.

Answer (score 1):

Show compassion for others. If you really have achievement you can benefit others very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond any doubt you have had an extraordinary experience that has the marks of Enlightenment as defined by Theravadin Buddhism. However, I doubt your experience was that of samadhi (which sometimes follows Enlightenment), because you clearly had some insights, such as “Like I was in deep sleep since I was a kid and I finally woke up,” “I felt like everything including me were connected,” “I was looking the world outside and everybody was like zombies of their own minds. And I realized that I used to be like them too,” “It was like I was sleeping in my entire life and I finally woke up in the real world,” “I was looking the trees, the birds and the fountain like I had never seen anything like this before,” and “I realized that everything is much more than we understand.” Where does it come from? From a traditional point of view, it had to come from having had similar experiences over many lifetimes. Why? Your core intelligence (Bodhicitta) has the function of bringing you up to speed asap. Very few confused or maladaptive sankhara stood in your way, allowing your core intelligence to cause you to experience key insights that were already present in your core intelligence, which is ordinarily unconscious. What is next? The traditional Theravadin answer is you study the Abhidharma. For more information about that path, you can read by book, *The Path of Love*.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! Many would dwell in their barkwood, "emptiness", if they have gained, taking it for heart wood.

Aside that [concentration can be wrong concentration](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than_en.html#s1), based on wrong view, leading to wrong release:

> from: [Maha Saropama Sutta: The Longer Heartwood-simile Discourse](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.029.than_en.html)
>
> "Just as if a man in need of heartwood, seeking heartwood, wandering in search of heartwood — passing over the heartwood of a great standing tree possessed of heartwood, passing over the sapwood — cutting away the inner bark, were to go off carrying it, thinking, 'heartwood.' A man with good eyesight, seeing him, would say, 'Ah, how this good man didn't know heartwood, didn't know sapwood, didn't know inner bark, didn't know outer bark, didn't know twigs & leaves! That's why he, in need of heartwood, seeking heartwood, wandering in search of heartwood — passing over the heartwood of a great standing tree possessed of heartwood, passing over the sapwood — cutting away the inner bark, went off carrying it, thinking, "heartwood." Whatever heartwood-business he had with heartwood, his purpose won't be served.'
>
> "In the same way, monks, there is the case where a certain son of good family, out of conviction, goes forth from the home life into homelessness, [thinking,] '...Perhaps the end of this entire mass of stress might be discerned!' Having thus gone forth, he encounters gain, offerings, & fame. He is not gratified with that gain, offerings, & fame, his resolve not fulfilled. He is not intoxicated with that gain, offerings, & fame, not heedless about it, and does not fall into heedlessness. Being heedful, he achieves consummation in virtue. He is gratified with that consummation in virtue, but his resolve is not fulfilled. Because of that consummation in virtue he does not exalt himself or disparage others. He is not intoxicated with that consummation in virtue, not heedless about it, and does not fall into heedlessness. Being heedful, he achieves consummation in concentration. He is gratified with that consummation in concentration, his resolve fulfilled. Because of that consummation in concentration he exalts himself and disparages others: 'I am concentrated, my mind at singleness, but these other monks are unconcentrated, their minds scattered.' He is intoxicated with that consummation in concentration, heedless about it, and falls into heedlessness. Being heedless, he dwells in suffering & stress. This, monks, is called a monk who grasps the inner bark of the holy life, and with that he falls short...

So best to gain and put effort into gain of right view, so that such question does not arisen [right effort](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than_en.html)! Again and again and focus proper, *yoniso manasikhara*, on arise and decay to get disenchanted and gain release.

Worthy to note: even one dwells heedful but having not gained right view yet, one is still an outsider. But even one dwelks heedless (not doing Jhana) but having alreadygained right view, is called an insider (Noble One). That is why a teacher of right view, ne possessing right view (e.g. a Noble One), is regarded higher as a teacher of Jhana. So if avaliable, don't seek for "meditation" teacher (because it brings pleasure) but for right view teacher, which can be of cause painful, according to your character and past. Being able to travel, possessing such skill, does not lead to release, [goes not beyond the Cosmos](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8118.msg12362.html#msg12362).

> As he was standing there he said to the Blessed One: "Is it possible, lord, by traveling, to know or see or reach a far end of the cosmos where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away or reappear?"
>
> "I tell you, friend, that it is not possible by traveling to know or see or reach a far end of the cosmos where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away, or reappear."

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score -1):

So let me get this straight' you have connected to a higher intelligence with a higher understanding and vision and you are asking us the servants of Ego whats next?

Maybe you should ask that question next time you experience that state and give us the answer.

Comment: I'm only a human just like you. It was an experience that just happenned to me, just like that. As I said I had no idea what it was... I was only wondering if I was an x-men. I never meditated before, I'm only focusing in my job, software development. I wanted to share my experience and find some answers. I wish everyone could get into this state. There are many people who can possibily answer and they are already in this state and beyond right now and any time in history.

Comment: No, we are not humans. We are the expression and materialization of a higher-force, a higher infinite intelligence Brahman if you want to name the One that cannot be named but is the name of all things. Our consciousness rise from it like waves from the ocean and like the waves when we finish our journey we return to the ocean.HUMAN is just an experience.Ego check, please!

Comment: Did the Buddha mention a higher state / force / intelligence? Perhaps you can cite that in your answer?

Comment: @nocomprende That comment names "the One that cannot be named" as "Brahman" -- see also e.g. [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/23626/254).